# "Insert into" doesn't works with node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want a simple query for an user registration form on node.js and mysql (insert into).

This query doesn't work: it doesn't insert data in the database, I'm not sure if it is the correct way to call the query.

```
app.route('/adminpanel/registeruser')

.post(function(req, res) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            connection.release();
        } else {
            var username = req.body.username,
                password = req.body.password,
                name = req.body.name,
                email = req.body.email,        
                company = req.body.company,
                active = req.body.active,
                myquery = "INSERT INTO `oneclick`.`oc_users` (`username`,     `password`, `name`, `email`, `company`, `active`) SET ('" + username + "', '" + password + "', '" + name + "', '" + email + "', '', '" + company + "', '" + active + "')";
                connection.query(myquery, function(err, rows) {
                connection.release();   
                res.redirect('/adminpanel/newuser');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Use mongodb with nodejs. Much funner and easier. https://www.mongodb.org/

Comment: So in the callback, did you log the errors ?

Comment: I cant see the logs, so I dont know where the error is, even if the connection is working.

Comment: @tehnuty What a ridiculous answer.  What database you use depends on your data and what you're doing with it, not on the application you use to access it.

Comment: @Brad What a ridiculous reply. He said he is new to nodejs so I recommended him mongodb

Comment: @tehnuty MongoDB has nothing to do with Node.js, and the fact that he is new to Node.js is precisely why you shouldn't confuse the two.  It's a very common misconception that because you're using the Node.js ecosystem that you should choose your database engine this way.  Teaching new folks this will only lead to poor decisions.  Choose what you need for your project.

Comment: ^ this. Choosing between a noSql and a sql solution is a design matter and depends on the data which has to be stored, not the programming language implementing the storage. Using mysql with nodejs is rediciously easy so if the data is suppose to be relational then sql is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

### You're attempting to mix up an insert statement and an update statement

This is what you're doing:

```
INSERT INTO [...] ([...]) SET [...]
```

This is not possible; the **SET** keyword is only applied for update statements.

**You should be using:**

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

**An update statement looks like this:**

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

You're simply mixing them together, it has nothing to do with nodejs.

Note: take a look on how to prepare your statements to query them in a save manner.

Answer (score 1):

It is not `SET` but `VALUES`, you have to change that.
Also, take care about SQL Injections.

Answer (score 0):

You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and it's also likely the reason your query isn't working.

Never concatenate data directly into a query like this.  It isn't being escaped properly, so any reserved character becomes ambiguous.  Use a parameterized query.  How you do this specifically depends on whatever you're using to connect to your database, which you didn't tell us.